# How can I create a list of strings in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How can I create list of `String`  in Haskell in order to use it in a function which takes the list and a word as arguments and looks for the same `Char` from a word  in the list of `String`? Should I use Data.Map or Data.List for creating a list? 
I've tried creating it like this:

```
dictionary :: [String]
dictonary = fromList ["wit","ass","bad","shoe","cold","pie","and","or"]
```

Comment: Remove `fromList` and you are done. The brackets already form a list, there's no need to do anything else.

Comment: Well if you want a *list* of strings, I do not see why you need a `fromList`. You already constructed a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
import Data.List
let checkIfContains :: [String] -> String -> Integer
checkIfContains x y = elemIndex y x
```

Then an example of running this would be:

```
checkIfContains ["lol", "heh"] "heh"

output: Just 1
```

So if you input a list of Strings **x** and a String **y** to see if **y** is in **x**, then the output is the index **y** in **x** (as here we found "heh" in index 1 of x). If **y** is not in **x** the output should be

```
Nothing
```

Thing to note, this function finds the first occurrence of y in x, so if if you have two entries of y in x, then it'll show the index of the first occurrence.